# Loop that displays all posts by logged in user, with Post Edit link

Tags: loop

I need a loop that pulls in all posts that were authored by the logged-in user.

I have to then create a link to the post with this in the querystring: ?_ninja_forms_action=edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$posts = get_posts(
    array(
        'post_author' => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_status' => 'any',
        'post_type'   => 'any',
    )
);

foreach ( $posts as $post )
    printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a><br />',
        esc_attr(
            add_query_arg( '_ninja_forms_action', 'edit', get_permalink( $post ) )
        ),
        get_the_title( $post )
    );
```